# Need assistance in displaying tree like structure in angular 5

Tags: angular, lodash

As i am a bit new to Angular 5, I am having hard time displaying the following json in the format below.Refer to image.

Also i have added the sample output json.

```
Sample Json:


{
  "shape": [{
    "id": "1",
    "shapeDetails": [
      {
        "name": "someShape1",
        "number": "10",
        "identifier": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "someShape1",
        "number": "10",
        "identifier": "222"
      },
      {
        "name": "someShape2",
        "number": "30",
        "identifier": "333"
      }
    ],
    "task": {
      "title": "first level",
      "key": "",
      "value": "",
      "childtask": [
        {
          "title": "second level1",
          "key": "number",
          "value": "10",
          "childtask": [
            {
              "title": "third level1",
              "key": "identifier",
              "value": "111",
              "childtask": []
            },
            {
              "title": "third level2",
              "key": "identifier",
              "value": "222",
              "childtask": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "second level2",
          "key": "number",
          "value": "30",
          "childtask": []
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

> PseudoCode
>    `1.Iterate through the task. 
>       2.  print the first level info
>       3.  go to second level
>       4.  get the key and value
>       5.  match the key value with shapeDetails.
>       6.  get that matching details.
>       7.  go to third level
>       8.  get the key and value
>       9.  match the key value with shapeDetails.
>       10. get that matching details.
>       11. Put the third level under the matching second level shape details`

I need to display above json in this way in Angular ui.
image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqsHm.jpg.Since shapeDetails can have max 2000 objects, what will be the optimal solution for it?
    Also, task will have only 3 levels not more than that.

I have added output json below:

```
Expected Output:

{
  "shape": [
    {
      "firstLevelDetails": {
        "title": "first level",
        "secondLevelDetails": [
          {
            "title": "second level1",
            "shapeDetail": {
              "name": "someShape1"//associated with number 10
            },
            "thirdLevelDetails": [
              {
                "title": "third level1"//identifier associated with number 10
              },
              {
                "title": "third level2"//identifier associated with number 10
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "second level2",
            "shapeDetail": {
              "name": "someShape2" //associated with number 30
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it looks like this is your homework. Please show what you've done and tried.

Comment: This is not my homework. This is my work. Working in Angular 5. I cannot paste what i have done. Because it will be against my office policy. I have even modified the json . To modify what i have done so that i can display here is a lot of task.

Comment: please provide your expected json output

Comment: I have provide the output in the question.

Comment: I have written the solution and is working fine. Thanks to  @AmayaSan.
I never thought of creating output json and coding according to that. As you asked it. I made the json and wrote code that gives the output json and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use existing npm packages which provides tree views.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tree-component

https://angular2-tree.readme.io/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/devextreme

Following is the plunker which shows data as tree like structure using devextreme package.

https://plnkr.co/edit/fyAPdSkOF8nD8ddmEvBi?p=preview

dx-tree-view component is used as below:

```
<dx-tree-view
    id="simple-treeview"
    [items]="products"
    [width]="300"
    (onItemClick)="selectItem($event)"
></dx-tree-view>
<div id="product-details" *ngIf="currentItem.price">
    <img [src]="currentItem.image" />
    <div class="name">{{currentItem.text}}</div>
    <div class="price">{{"$" + currentItem.price}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not sure if this helps. Will definitely try.